# vscodeでインテリセンスの優先度を変更したいんですがどうすればいいですか？

Tags: javascript, vscode

具体的に言うとflowtypeの補完を一番上にしたいです。
例えば、以下の状況ではキーワードの補完ではなく、countを優先してほしいです。
[image: vscode]

Atomで同様の補完を行うと以下になります。
vscodeでもこのようにflowの優先度を上げる、もしくはflow以外の補完状況を非表示にしたいです。
[image: atom]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Add Option to Exclude Names From Suggestion Lists in JavaScript Files #26595](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/26595)

[IntelliSense mixed with word-based suggestions #100](https://github.com/flowtype/flow-for-vscode/issues/100)

この問題に該当しますか? そうであれば `"javascript.nameSuggestions": false` で解決できる可能性があります。